# Windows 7 guest in hyper-v cant start after setup

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I have a windows 10 Laptop and I'm trying to install Windows 7 guest OS in hyper-V.

The setup goes fine (I even got past date/password/updates configuration page). After the setup , it's not booting up, it's stuck with a blank screen and a blinking cursor. if I attach a disk drive containing windows 7 and restart the guest it gives me the setup screen again (I need to press some key though as it says).

But a debian (Kali-Linux) guest runs fine!

I allotted a 40GB VHD and provided it with 2GB ram ( host has 4GB of ram ). It's a lenovo z570 laptop. I tried both 64b and 32b ones (32b is the one that I want actually!)

**P.S:** The problem is solved. Thanks for your support though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your support buddies! I solved my problem. I just ran into a fix that is intended for a real pc and it worked.I followed the instructions stated in this website - [Windows won't boot. Black screen with blinking cursor at the corner](http://fbinotto.blogspot.in/2011/08/windows-7-wont-boot-black-screen-with.html)

But I used "D:\" instead of "C:\" though (I don't know why! I tried it cause bcdedit command gave results regarding D:\ drive. it's appreciable if someone could tell me why).

Thanks again guys!

Answer (score 1):

Did you create a Generation 2  or Generation 1 VM?  If you really want that 32bit system to boot I believe it will need to be a Generation 1 [[source]](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ausoemteam/2015/04/21/deciding-when-to-use-generation-1-or-generation-2-virtual-machines-with-hyper-v/).

Comment: Nope, it didn't work buddy!!!

Answer (score -1):

SIMPLE solution to this problem exists,

.Create a new Virtual Machine on your Hyper-V (Server 2008 R2).
.Install Windows 7 from a DVD or an ISO file, whatever makes you happy.
. On the final reboot of the install, you will, of course, get the above mentioned black screen.
.Reboot the VM, but this time press a key to boot from the Windows 7 DVD (or boot from your ISO) so that you can get into the repair mode (recovery console/DOS prompt).
. Type C: to go to the C (boot) drive of your Windows 7 VM.

Here's the magic:

.Simply type the following command at the recovery console DOS prompt:

bootsect.exe /nt60 all /force

.type EXIT and then reboot the machine.

Comment: Why would the user need to create a *new* virtual machine to do this?